# How to pair every item in a 2 lists as fractions until the end of said lists?

Tags: python, list

Given the following two lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

How to append them to a list to get the results below?

```
c = [1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9, 1/10, 2/6... 5/10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> map(Fraction, a, b)  # In Python 3.x: list(map(Fraction, a, b))
[Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(3, 8), Fraction(4, 9), Fraction(1, 2)]
```

You can also use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> [Fraction(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(3, 8), Fraction(4, 9), Fraction(1, 2)]
```

**UPDATE** To get cartesian product

Using list comprehension (you can use multiple `for` clauses):

```
>>> [Fraction(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
[Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1, 7), Fraction(1, 8), ....
 Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(5, 9), Fraction(1, 2)]
```

Comment: What if the number of characters in the list is not definite? Since it is up to the user to input a number, the factors differ.

Comment: @VaguelyUnderstandable, Sorry I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One last tiny thing. is there any way to make the pairs appear as fractions (as in like "1/6" instead of "Fraction(1, 6)")? I need the program to output it as fractions since I would need to append them to a new list again.

Comment: @VaguelyUnderstandable, Convert Fraction object to string object usign `str`: `[str(Fraction(x, y)) for x in a for y in b]`, or just just format string from the beginning if you don't need fraction operator: `['{}/{}'.format(x, y) for x in a for y in b]`

Comment: YUP! Works great now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.product` to generate pairs of numbers from `a` and `b`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> fracs = [Fraction(*pair) for pair in itertools.product(a, b)]
>>> fracs
[Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1, 7), Fraction(1, 8), ... 
..., Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(5, 9), Fraction(1, 2)]
```

This also works if the lists `a` and `b` are not of equal length.